# Python House Adventure - How to give a different output if you have already entered a room once

Tags: python, adventure

So basically, I am making a text adventure game using python and the objective is to find a prize somewhere in the house based on clues and riddles. When you enter a room in the house by telling the programs if you want to go North, South, East or West it gives you a description of the room but in some cases when you enter a room there is nowhere else to go other than the room you just came from so I want to make it so a different output it given to you if you have already entered a room in the house. How would I do that?

```
class bc:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

inventory = []
chest = "Chest"
key = "Key"
book = "Book"
picture = "Picture"

def playGame():
    location = "Porch"
    show_intro()
    while not (location == "Exit"):
        showRoom(location)
        direction = str(input(bc.BOLD + bc.HEADER + "Which direction 
do you want to go?: \n" + bc.ENDC))
        location = pickRoom(direction, location)

def show_intro():
    print(bc.BOLD + """Welcome to a game with no graphics so you get 
more FPS's!
Old man Mesarosh lived here years ago before he and his wife suddenly 
disappeared.
Before he died, it was said that he left behind a chest full of 
treasure.
It's your job to figure out where he left it, and fast...
Police drive by every 30 minutes searching for teens exploring the 
abandoned house
Find the clues left behind by Mesarosh and find where the treasure is 
hidden.
Type "North", "South", "East" or "West" to decide which way to go.
Good luck! \n""" + bc.ENDC)

def pickRoom(direction, room):
    while True:
        if(direction == "quit") or (direction == "exit"):
            print("Better luck next time!")
            return "Exit"
        elif room == "Porch":
            if direction.lower() == "north":
                return "Pantry"
        elif room == "Pantry":
            if direction.lower() == "north":
                return "Kitchen"
            elif direction.lower() == "east":
                return "DiningRoom"
        elif room == "DiningRoom":
            if direction.lower() == "west":
                return "Pantry"
        elif room == "Kitchen":
            if direction.lower() == "west":
                return "LivingRoom"
            elif direction.lower() == "east":
                return "Bedroom"
        elif room == "Bedroom":
            if direction.lower() == "west":
                return "Kitchen"
        elif room == "LivingRoom":
            if direction.lower() == "west":
                return "Bathroom"
            elif direction.lower() == "north":
                return "Stairs"
        elif room == "Bathroom":
            if direction.lower() == "east":
                return "LivingRoom"
        elif room == "Stairs":
            if direction.lower() == "south":
                return "Bar"
        elif room == "Bar":
            if direction.lower() == "east":
                return "Shop"
        elif room == "Shop":
            if direction.lower() == "north":
                return "Closet"
            elif direction.lower() == "south":
                return "Storage"
        elif room == "Storage":
            if direction.lower() == "north":
                return "Shop"
        elif room == "Closet":
            if direction.lower() == "south":
                return "Shop"


def showRoom(room):
    if room == "Porch": #Done
        showPorch()
    elif room == "Pantry": #Done
        showPantry()
    elif room == "Kitchen": #Done
        showKitchen()
    elif room == "DiningRoom": #Done
        showDining()
    elif room == "Bedroom": #Done
        showBedroom()
    elif room == "LivingRoom": #Done
        showLiving()
    elif room == "Bathroom": #Done
        showBathroom()
    elif room == "Stairs": #Done
        showStairs()
    elif room == "Bar": #Done
        showBar()
    elif room == "Shop": #Done
        showShop()
    elif room == "Storage": #Done
        showStorage()
    elif room == "Closet": #Done
        showCloset()

playGame()
```

Comment: This is more a question about implementation than an actual code question. I recommend reading the help page and How To Ask as this is probably off topic. To answer your question though, you'd need some way to track when a room is entered. This variable would control the 'state' of your text adventure and you could write If statements or other program flow to control how this 'state' affects your adventure. If you have a specific programming problem that would make for an on topic question. I would suggest a revision in this sense. Advice on projects is for a different stack

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable that has a different value after a player has entered the room. You can initialize a flag or counter at the beginning of the game, check it before you display the message, then set it (for a flag) or increment it (for a counter) when the player enters the room.

Comment: Oh god I didn't think about that. I was trying to create an empty list and when you enter a room that list is added to the room list and then check if the room is in the list when you enter again and if it is then it gives you a different output but that didn't end up working. Thanks man, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @ApexMC That doesn't sound like a bad approach if you want to track every room. If you post your code, we might be able to help troubleshoot why that doesn't work. (If you have a small map, though, individual flag variables should work fine.)

Comment: I added the code to the original post, theres a lot after what i posted which is just the dialog thats printed when you entered each room but I really didn't feel like indenting all of it into this site so yeah.

Comment: also I know, the dialog is very cheesy but it's for a freshman CS class in college so Its intentionally bad

Comment: @ApexMC Can you post one of those `showRoom` functions? That's the code where you would want to check a flag and display different messages.

Answer (score 0):

When a room is entered, set a variable. Make in if-else statement in every room checking the variable's value, and if the variable shows being changed to the you've-already-been-here state, show the you've-already-been-here message.